# Why does the list of unanswered questions have answers?

Tags: bug

When I view the [unanswered DIY questions](https://diy.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and click on them to see if I can answer them, I found the first *have* answers.  None were accepted, but still—doesn't "unanswered questions" mean zero answers?  Further down the list is a few with zero answers.

It acts like the list of questions with no *accepted* answer.

Also, do comments to the OP affect the selection of questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No answers" in Stack Exchange terms means no **upvoted**  answers. The fact that the existing answers haven't been upvoted means that no one else thinks that they are good answers so the system encourages other people to try to provide a better one.

Comment: Ah!  Thanks.  That does explain it.